# Remove MariaDB (MySQL) Databases

Tags: 16.04, mysql, root, database, mariadb

How do I completely remove MariaDB so I can reset the root password?

Comment: Sorry? What does the 1st have to do with the 2nd?  And even if you did mean to reset the password for connecting to the database and not the root password: what does that have to do with removing mariadb?

Comment: and how did you install mariadb? apt-get? source tarball?

Comment: I used apt-get I need to pretty much reset all the passwords to it but think Ive broken it to the stage a complete reset is easier than doing it manually

Comment: Re-installing the packages won't reset the database or its configuration though. This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). I think your question would be better along the lines of: “I broke my MariaDB installation and probably need to reset its root password. So far I tried […] to achieve that but it wasn't successful/seems to have made things worse. How can I proceed?” I won't vote to close it as unclear because there's a helpful answer though.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First, create a backup of {database}:

```
mysqldump -u {user} -p {database} > /home/$USER/Documents/backup.sql
```

To remove any trace of mariadb installed through apt-get:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo apt-get --purge remove "mysql*"
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/
```

and it is all gone. **Including databases and any configuration file.**

To check if anything named mysql is gone do a

```
sudo updatedb
```

and a

```
locate mysql
```

It should be fairly empty (maybe some manual pages or a connector). If though you see a `my.cnf` amongst the results remove that too.

Comment: // , I know this is Ask Ubuntu, but do you have any ideas for how to do this without using the package manager?

Comment: That depends on the OS you want it for.

Answer (score -1):

This is what worked for me on Kali Linux:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql   
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep mariadb
```

Remove all the packages found by the above commands.

```
sudo dpkg --force depends --purge mysql-common
```

I found these libraries:

```
libdbd-mariadb-perl             install
libmariadb-dev                  install
libmariadb-dev-compat               install
libmariadb3:amd64               install
libmariadbd-dev                 install
libmariadbd19:amd64             install
mariadb-backup                  install
mariadb-client                  install
mariadb-client-core             install
mariadb-common                  install
mariadb-plugin-provider-bzip2           install
mariadb-plugin-provider-lz4         install
mariadb-plugin-provider-lzma            install
mariadb-plugin-provider-lzo         install
mariadb-plugin-provider-snappy          install
mariadb-server-core             install
mariadb-test-data   
default-libmysqlclient-dev:amd64        install
default-libmysqld-dev:amd64         install
default-mysql-client-core           install
mysql-common                    deinstall
python3-mysqldb                 install
```

To remove them run

```
sudo apt autoremove                                        
sudo apt autoclean
```

If any conflict comes up, you can use the `dpkg` command to remove a package and then reinstall if needed.