# Unable to launch mariadb server

Tags: 16.04, server, mysql, mariadb

I'm using ubuntu 16.04, but let's say i'm still kind of noobish on the subject.

I already had Mysql installed when I wanted to install MariaDB, and while it installed, it seems that MariaDB force uninstalled Mysql to take its place. However, when trying to launch the server, I have the following:

```
Configuring mariadb-server-10.1 (10.1.22-3) ...
Job for mariadb.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Fri 2017-05-26 00:52:18 CEST; 11ms ago
  Process: 14410 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 14320 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 14316 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 14314 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 14410 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

mai 26 00:50:45 jaeger767-OMEN systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
mai 26 00:50:46 jaeger767-OMEN mysqld[14410]: 2017-05-26  0:50:46 140701379916352 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.22-MariaDB-) starting as process 14410 ...
mai 26 00:52:16 jaeger767-OMEN systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
mai 26 00:52:18 jaeger767-OMEN systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
mai 26 00:52:18 jaeger767-OMEN systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
mai 26 00:52:18 jaeger767-OMEN systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
dpkg: 
Package processing error mariadb-server-10.1 (--configure) : the under-process script post-installation returned an exit error code 1
```

Now I can't uninstall MariaDB without Ubuntu wanting to configure it, and I don't know how to fix this, I found some stuff about this on StackExchange, but it didn't work

Thank you in advance

Comment: If I run "sudo apt-get purge mariadb-server" or the same with "mysql-server", it still wants to configure mariadb-server, that's why I'm asking for help

Comment: Check here https://askubuntu.com/questions/806107/remove-mariadb-mysql-databases, for help uninstalling

Comment: do `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: @George thank you for your link, it worked! (and I tried your command some time ago but it didn't)

Comment: See : https://askubuntu.com/questions/750604/why-does-mariadb-keep-dying-how-do-i-stop-it Explanation of the issue and how to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

Like ChrisAga stated it in the comments:

> See : [askubuntu.com/questions/750604/…](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750604/why-does-mariadb-keep-dying-how-do-i-stop-it) Explanation of the issue and how to solve it.

This is an AppArmor issue that can be fixed by configuring AppArmor to only complain about the mysqld process.

Here's a summary of the commands of the accepted answer in that link.

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils
sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/mysqld
sudo service apparmor reload
sudo systemctl start mariadb
```