# Remove Mariadb 10.3 and Mysql completely from Ubuntu

Tags: package-management, 18.04, mysql, mariadb

I have been trying to remove all the package.

```
apt-get remove --purge mysql*
apt-get remove --purge mysql
apt-get remove --purge mariadb
apt-get remove --purge mariadb*
apt-get --purge remove mariadb-server
apt-get --purge remove python-software-properties
```

But after `apt-get remove --purge mysql*`, they need me to run  `apt --fix-broken install` first

Try to remove mariadb `apt-get remove --purge mariadb*` and get

```
`Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.`
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: unable to read mariadb.service
```

Try to start mysql and get this

```
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
```

What should i do to remove all of it?

Comment: what if you reinstall and then remove and purge? like `sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server && sudo apt-get remove -y --purge mysql*`, then with mariadb the same as `sudo apt-get install -y mariadb-server && sudo apt-get remove -y --purge mariadb-server`. I think mysql and mariadb install the same binary files ( mariadb is a drop-in replacement), so it will complain on the service on the second remove.

Comment: @bistoco it said `You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server-10.3 : PreDepends: mariadb-common (>= 1:10.3.10+maria~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: mariadb-client-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.10+maria~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: mariadb-server-core-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.10+maria~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
`

Comment: @bistoco and install mariadb again but get error at `Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
`

Comment: [Try this](https://askubuntu.com/a/948428/260379), is using `dpkg` and forcing the uninstall.

Comment: @bistoco i did `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all package-name`. For some package is succeced. then i execute `dpkg -l | grep -e mysql -e mariadb`, "mariadb-serber-10.3" is still there

Comment: when i execute `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all mariadb-server-10.3`, it said `Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.3 (--purge):
 installed mariadb-server-10.3 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: unable to read mariadb.service`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Purge mariadb

   ```
   sudo apt purge mariadb-*
   ```

   Remove all databases ('Yes' answer)
2. Purge mysql

   ```
   sudo apt purge mysql-*
   ```

   Remove all databases ('Yes' answer)
3. Remove mariadb repo from `/etc/apt/sources.list`

   Find something like this:

   ```
   deb [arch=amd64,arm64,ppc64el] http://mariadb.mirror.globo.tech/repo/10.4/ubuntu bionic main
   ```
4. Remove folders:

   ```
   sudo rm -r /usr/share/mysql/
   sudo rm -r /etc/mysql/
   sudo rm -r /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service
   ```
5. Now you can try to install oracle mysql:

   ```
   sudo apt install mysql-server
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I had success dealing with a similar problem by following the some of the steps listed in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946646/install-of-mysql-server-after-mariadb-fails/948428#948428).

> 1. Detect all MariaDB and MySQL packages
>
>    ```
>    apt search mariadb | grep "\[install"
>    ```
>
>    and
>
>    ```
>    apt search mysql | grep "\[install"
>    ```

Unfortunately, before I was able to do the next step, I had to remove the various `mariadb.service` files, so that `dpkg` was able to remove the `mariadb-server-10.3` package properly. Otherwise, it seems to be assuming there's a running service, and when it's unable to stop it (because the symlink is broken), it errors out.

I found `mariadb.service` in `/etc/systemd/system` and `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants`

> 2. Force uninstall of all MariaDB and MySQL packages (server, client, libs) to clean the mess
>
>    ```
>    sudo dpkg --force depends --purge <package> <package> ...
>    ```

For the "Step 4" of that post, I swapped the order of the commands to remove the unneeded packages first:

```
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
```

And then I was able to reinstall per the normal

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can completely uninstall **mysql / mariadb** as follow:

```
sudo apt-get purge mariadb-server mariadb-* mysql-*
```

The **purge** is identical to **remove**, except that packages are removed and purged (any configuration files are deleted too)